# Создание игровой валюты на python и перенос на Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, разработка-игр, aiogram

Как на `python` сделать **игровую валюту**, например что-бы можно было её отслеживать. То есть эта **валюта** должна рандомно то расти, то падать. Ваозможно ли такое сделать? Если да, то можно ли, такое сделать в теллеграм боте на `aiogramm`

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для своей валюты вам необходимо конвертировать реальную в виртуальную, для этого можно создать какую-нибудь переменную `курса` вашей валюты и при пополнении баланса вы можете воспользоватьс следующим синтаксисом:

`баланс = сумма полполнения * курс`

для изменения курса рандомом почитайте [Этот сайт](https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-random.html) и выбирете подходящий вам метод. По поводу вывода подумайте сами как можно проводить обратную конвертацию